# Get mp3 file from server by fetch

Tags: node.js

I have a server written in node.js. The client sends a get request by fetch with the url of the mp3 file that is in the files on the server. My goal is to send the mp3 file back to the client so that it can be played. I wrote something like this:

```
if (req.url.indexOf(".mp3") != -1) {
                fs.readFile(__dirname + decodeURI(req.url), function (error, data) {
                    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                    res.writeHead(200, {
                        "Content-type": "audio/mpeg",
                    });
                    res.write(data);
                    res.end();
                })
            }
```

but I get this error: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0

Also, here it is client side:

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/static/mp3/" + value, { method: "get" })
        .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => (this.song = data));
document.getElementById("audio_src").src =
        "http://localhost:3000/" + this.song;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the client, you're calling `response.json()`, but the response you're getting back is NOT json.  The data you're getting back is binary.  Perhaps you should be calling `response.blob()`?

But, then you're trying to put the binary data into a URL as text.  And, you're not handling the asynchronous nature of `fetch()` properly either.  No, this is not the way to do things.  You could create a data encoded URL, but there's really no point in doing it that way since whatever audio element you're using the the HTML page can fetch the MP3 from the URL by itself.

---

I might suggest something simpler in the client:

```
document.getElementById("audio_src").src = "http://localhost:3000/static/mp3/" + value;
```

And, let the browser's html tag go get the MP3 for you.  I'm assuming that the element represented by `audio_src` is something that knows how to play MP3 audio sources on it's own.  If so, that means you just give it the URL and it will go fetch it and play it on its own.